# Remove WordPress theme from a specific page

Tags: customization, child-pages

There is a site with WordPress installed and a theme selected. I have created an HTML page for the site, but it wasn't looking well with the theme. So, I want to put the page on the site without any theme, and just the way I wrote the code, without disabling the theme from any other pages.

Is there an easy way to do it without messing with the theme? And if there isn't, then I am willing to modify theme files, but how should I go about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is, in fact, a way to do it without messing with the theme, let's say your WordPress is on `public_html/your_site`, now you want to create an HTML page that is on `your_site.com/mypage`, so instead of creating a page or post called `mypage` on your WordPress dashboard you are going to create a **mypage.html** and upload it to `public_html/your_site`, in case you want to get rid of the .html you can simply hide it from your **.htaccess** doing something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Keep in mind any tracking code you have on your WordPress, for example, Google Analytics, if you are using things like that you will have to add those codes to your HTML page as well.

Answer (score 3):

Just make a directory on the highest level and put your html file there. If you call it directly, you will bypass WordPress. Beware that this also means the file won't be found using WP's search function. Basically, for WP, it will be an external page.